# Replacing specific strings in all matching files content with the file's basename using PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace, basename

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Zac\Downloads\script test\script test\*.txt' -Recurse | ForEach {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace '1000', $fileNameOnly}) | Set-Content $_ }
```

I have been trying to use a simple PowerShell script to replace the `1000` value in my documents with the goal of replacing the value with the name of the `.nc1/.txt` file it is editing.

For example a file that is called `BM3333.nc1` has a line value of `1000` which needs to replace it with `BM3333` so on, so forth. This will be used in batch editing.

What is the variable that I use for replacing the `1000` with the file name?
So far, I can get this to run but it doesn't replace the `1000` value, it removes it.

Comment: `$fileNameOnly` has never been defined in your code so it makes sense the word `1000` is being removed then

Comment: `Get-Content` has an optional parameter `-Raw` that returns the whole file as a single string. This allows you to issue a single `.Replace('1000', $fileNameOnly`) for each file, then write it out at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that inside the ScriptBlock of a `ForEach-Object` invocation, the variable is `$_` (also known as `$PSItem`). There is no name for the inner script to get the value from the outer script.

You need to create a unique name in the outer script beforehand. The ScriptBlock argument to `ForEach-Object` does not need to be a single expression. You can either use multiple lines or a `;`.

`1..3 | ForEach-Object { $a = $_; 100..105 | ForEach-Object { $_ * $a } }`

For your use case, you need this variable to be the name of the file. The values in the outer ScriptBlock are `System.IO.FileSystemInfo`, which were returned by `Get-ChildInfo`.

PowerShell makes iterating on work like this very easy; try seeing which properties are available:

`Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Zac\Downloads\script test\script test\*.txt' -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1 | Format-List *`